# Linking Shared Object Files with QMake/CMake

Tags: linux, cmake, qt-creator, qmake

Im trying to link a (.so) file in Qt Creator. I've tried in both CMake and QMake and get the same error. Here is my code in QMake:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/opt/workswell/wic_sdk/include"
LIBS +=-L/opt/workswell/wic_sdk/lib
LIBS += -lWIC_SDK
```

I've always used this for (.dll) files but when trying to use (.so) files I get this error:

```
/opt/workswell/wic_sdk/lib/libWIC_SDK.so:-1: error: file not recognized: file format not recognized
```

From what I can find online they are meant to be used the same way so I'm at a bit of a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit:
Thanks to the comments for pointing me in the right direction. Turned out this was a 64-bit library and my compiler was 32-bit. The error message made it sound like something else was the issue so there we are.

Comment: Your `libWIC_SDK.so` is probably not a shared library. Use the `file` command to find out.

Comment: it returns this: `libWIC_SDK.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=352f9e933cbef22ae165afe32987f8852bdb993f, not stripped
`

Comment: So, library `libWIC_SDK.so` is built for ARM. Do you build your project for ARM platform too?

Comment: Yeah this is on a Pi 4

Comment: That `-1` in the error message looks strange. It looks like the file is attempted to read **line by line**, but it is known that libraries and objects files have binary format, for which lines are meaningless. Please, show (add to the question post) **complete** error message. That message should include the tool (`gcc`, `ld`, etc.) which runs this step and emits the error message.

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit OS on your Pi 4?